# Shell - Set command output to a variable and replace

Tags: shell, certutil

I am developing a PowerShell script for calculating checksum of zip files. I have to execute it in both W7 and W10. I have noticed that certUtil commmand returns strings like A2 5B 8A... in W7, but in W10 it returns the same string but without spaces. So I decided to remove the spaces to uniform it, setting the output to a variable and then remove the spaces... but it does not work.

```
for /f  "delims=" %%f in ('dir %~dp0*.zip /b') do (
    echo %%~f:
    $result = certUtil -hashfile "%~dp0%%~f" SHA512 | find /i /v "SHA512" | 
        find /i /v "certUtil"
    $result = $result -replace '\s', ''
    echo %result%
    set /a counter += 1
    echo.
)
```

Do you know how to remove them?

Comment: This is some weird mesh of Shell and Powershell. This wouldnt work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I have to use only Shell, I mixed it with another script I am developing :/ . Here Powershell is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems in your example you are using Shell Commands like For, Echo, Set and then you mixed in powershell commands like $

You should use all powershell since you said you were working on a powershell script.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\TEST" -Include *.zip -File -Recurse | %{
    Get-FileHash $_ -Algorithm SHA512 | select Path, Hash
}
```

This gets all zip files in Test in and then using Get-Filehash we then use the Sha512 algorithm. Return the Path of File and Hash.

This will require atleast Powershell 4.0

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I have to use only Shell, I mixed it with another script I am developing :/ . Here Powershell is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that works with the builtin powershell versions on both 7 and 10 (version 2 and 5 respectively), I'd stick with `certutil`.

The second line of output from `certutil -hashfile` contains the hash, so grab that like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.zip -Recurse |ForEach-Object {
    # call certutil, grab second line of output (index 1)
    $hashString = @(certutil -hashfile """$($_.FullName)""" SHA512)[1]
    # remove any non-word characters from the output:
    [regex]::Replace($hashString,'[\W]','')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry, I have to use only Shell, I mixed it with another script I am developing :/ . Here Powershell is not allowed.